# Isotope hide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

My site has all elements displayed by default.

Isotope has the inbuilt method 'filter' - ie show ONLY this.

I'd like to make a function where I hide/show an element based on clicking on a button on screen - ie hide ONLY this (and show the others) / unhide this (and show the others).

Here's what I'm doing code-wise.

```
var music = $('#music').isotope();

$('nav button').on('click', function () {

    music.isotope({

        filter: "div." + $(this).attr("class")
    });
```

Comment: can you provide some HTML markup so we can see what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With filtering, the filter parameter must match items in your HTML markup, if not the filter will not return anything.

**FIDDLE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XWVhc/1/

I can only provide an alternate example as you have not provided any html markup so that we could debug your current code, however, I'll explain how this works.

**HTML FOR FILTERS:**

Here we have a few simple buttons that will filter our items with the `data-filter` attribute attached to each button.

```
<div id="filter-buttons-holder">
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter=".dog">DOG</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter=".cat">CAT</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter=".foo">FOO</div>
    <div class="filter-button" data-filter=".bar">BAR</div>
    <div class="filter-button selected" data-filter=".dog, .foo, .cat, .bar">SHOW ALL</div>
</div>
```

**HTML FOR ISOTOPE ITEMS:**

Here's the markup for our isotope items, notice that each item has a class of `isotope-item` and also has a class of what ***'category'*** it belongs too, you can add multiple classes and it will still filter as expected.

```
<div id="module-columns-holder" class="isotope"> 
    <a href="/" class="dog isotope-item"> 
        <div><h1>DOG</h1></div> 
    </a>  
        <a href="/" class="cat foo isotope-item"> 
        <div><h1>CAT</h1></div> 
    </a>  
    <a href="/" class="dog isotope-item"> 
        <div><h1>DOG</h1></div> 
    </a>  
    <a href="/" class="foo isotope-item"> 
        <div><h1>FOO</h1></div> 
    </a>  
    <a href="/" class="bar isotope-item"> 
        <div><h1>BAR</h1></div> 
    </a>  
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT FILTERING**

Here we set up our isotope container, notice the last data attribute is a filter, this is effectively what you're after, however you can specify which ***'category'*** you want to filter on initially.

```
//Setup isotope for filters
var isotopeContainer = $('#module-columns-holder');
isotopeContainer.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows',
    animationOptions : {
        queue : false,
        duration : 750,
        easing: 'linear'
    },
    filter: '.dog, .cat, .foo, .bar'
});
```

**CLICK EVENT FOR FILTERS**

You can attach a filter to the buttons we created earlier so that you can have live filtering

```
    $('#filter-buttons-holder .filter-button').on('click',function(){
        var filters = $(this).data('filter');
        var parent = $(this).closest('#filter-buttons-holder');
        parent.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        isotopeContainer.isotope({ filter: filters });
        return false;
    });
```

Hope this helps